# PDF attachment is not opening which I sent by php in Yahoo and some other email providers except gmail

Tags: php, pdf, phpmailer, email-attachments, yahoo

**This is my code.Here I am converting one of my html to pdf after that I attach it and send a mail along with one subject..**

*Subject also html only*
*Attachment can open from gmail but other mails like yahoo, hot mails are not responding well*
*This is Codeigniter (MVC) coding*

```
   $this->load->view('table2',$data);
    // Get output html
    $html = $this->output->get_output();

    // Load library
    $this->load->library('dompdf_gen');

    //PATH
    $path = FCPATH.'pdf_files/';
    $filename = 'Invoice_pdf'.date('dmYHis').'.pdf';
    $output_file = $path.$filename;
    $data['file_name'] = $this->config->item('base_url').'pdf_files/'.$filename;

    // Convert to PDF
    $this->dompdf->load_html($html);
    $this->dompdf->render();

    $this->dompdf->set_paper(array(0, 0, 792.00, 1224.00),'portrait');
    $output = $this->dompdf->output();
    file_put_contents($output_file, $output);


    // Mail Sending with attachments
    //echo $path; exit;
    $file = $path.$filename;
    $message1 = $this->load->view('mail_sub',$data, TRUE);
    //echo $message1; exit;
    $content = file_get_contents($file);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

    // a random hash will be necessary to send mixed content
    $separator = md5(time());

    // carriage return type (RFC)
    $eol = "\r\n";

    $to = 'example@example.com';


    $headers = "From: <accounts@example.com>" . $eol;
    $headers .= 'CC:'. $session_data['mailid'] ."\r\n";//$session_data['mailid']
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $separator . "\"" . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol;
    $headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message." . $eol;

    // message
    $body = "--" . $separator . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Type: text/HTML; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol;
    $body .= $message1."\r\n";
    // attachment
    $body .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $filename . "\"" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment" . $eol;
    $body .= $content . $eol;
    $body .= "--" . $separator . "--";
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Use a mail library like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) that avoids problems like this.

Comment: you can use code ignitor's own email function for attachment `$this->email->attach('/path/to/filename.ext');`